# Why do I get undefined method `mktmpdir' for Dir:Class in irb using Ruby 2.6.3?

Tags: ruby, directory, irb, temp

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/Dir.html contains a description about the `mktmpdir` method of the Dir class.

> mktmpdir(prefix_suffix=nil, *rest)
> ::mktmpdir creates a temporary directory.

An app uses it with no error but why it is not possible to run it in console / irb?

I have tested with `Dir.new ...` as well, below my attempt with `Dir.mktmpdir`.

```
irb(main):010:0> Dir.mktmpdir {|dir| dir is ".../d..." }
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from C:/Ruby26/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `<main>'
        4: from C:/Ruby26/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `load'
        3: from C:/Ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from (irb):10
        1: from (irb):10:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `mktmpdir' for Dir:Class)
```

`Dir.methods` is not showing this method but only mkdir.

What is missing respectively what is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're confusing the patches to the `Dir` class that `tmpdir` in the standard library adds with the plain unpatched `Dir` class in core. If you look at the `tmpdir` package's documentation:

> https://ruby-doc.com/stdlib/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/Dir.html

then you'll find `Dir.mktmpdir` (note the `stdlib/libdoc/tmpdir`) in the path. But if we look at `Dir` in core:

> https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html

you'll find all the usual class methods (`chdir`, `chroot`, ...) but no `mktmpdir`.

If you want to use `mktmpdir` then you have to `require 'tmpdir'`:

```
Dir.method(:mktmpdir)
# NameError (undefined method `mktmpdir' for class `#<Class:Dir>')

require 'tmpdir'
Dir.method(:mktmpdir)
# #<Method: Dir.mktmpdir>
```